# While unit React-native test files with Mocha, it gives error unexpected tocken

Tags: react-native, mocha.js, enzyme, chai

In a React-native project, I want to setup unit testing, For this I am using Mocha and Chai. When I run command `npm test` it executes `mocha __tests__/*.js` internally. In test file my code is following:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { RefundedEmd } from './RefundedEmd';
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('App', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    renderer.create(<App />);
  });
});
```

I get following error in console:

```
C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\__tests__\App-test.js:1
import { expect } from 'chai';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:311:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:308:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:849:10)
    at Object.exports.singleRun (C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:108:16)
    at exports.runMocha (C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:143:13)
    at Object.exports.handler.argv [as handler] (C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:305:3)
    at Object.runCommand (C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:242:26)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1087:28)
    at Object.parse (C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:566:25)
    at Object.exports.main (C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\cli.js:68:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Technical work\Lorex\slf-mobile-impl\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha:133:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```